# How to give access to ContentDocument for all users under one profile when it comes through email services?

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, contentdocument, inboundservices

Inbound Class:

```
    global class Topix_InboundEmailServiceHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler{

    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email,Messaging.Inboundenvelope envelope) {
        //Variable Declaration
        system.debug('email'+email);
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

        try{
            List<ContentVersion> content = new List<ContentVersion>();
            if(email.textAttachments != null){

                List<ContentDocument> Contentlist = [select id from ContentDocument where Title ='Out-Of-Stock'];
                system.debug('++++TextAttachement++Contentlist'+Contentlist);
                Delete  Contentlist;

                for (Messaging.InboundEmail.TextAttachment textAttachment : email.textAttachments) {
                    system.debug('++++TextAttachement222++Contentlist'+Contentlist);
                    ContentVersion con = new ContentVersion();
                    con.Title = 'Out-of-Stock';
                    // con.PathOnClient = 'Test_Image.jpg';
                    con.SharingPrivacy='N';
                    con.PathOnClient = '/' + 'OutOfStock.pdf';
                    con.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(textAttachment.body);
                    con.IsMajorVersion = true;
                    content.add(con);
                }
            }
            if(email.binaryAttachments != null){

                List<ContentDocument> Contentlist = [select id from ContentDocument where Title ='Out-Of-Stock'];
                system.debug('++++BinaryAttachement++Contentlist'+Contentlist);
                Delete  Contentlist;

                for (Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment binayAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
                    ContentVersion c = new ContentVersion();
                    c.Title = 'Out-of-Stock';
                    c.PathOnClient = '/' +  'OutOfStock.pdf';
                    //  c.PathOnClient = 'Test_Image.jpg';
                    c.VersionData = binayAttachment.body;
                    c.IsMajorVersion = true;
                    content.add(c);   
                }
            }                


            Insert content;


            system.debug('++++++++++attachmentList+++'+content);
            ContentVersion c= new ContentVersion();
            c = [select id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where title ='Out-of-Stock' limit 1];
            //   content = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :content.Id LIMIT 1];
            ContentWorkspace ws = [SELECT Id, RootContentFolderId FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = 'Out Of Stock Library' LIMIT 1];

            ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
            cdl.ContentDocumentId = c.ContentDocumentId;
            cdl.ShareType = 'I';
            cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
            cdl.LinkedEntityId = ws.Id; //Magic happens here
            insert cdl;

            system.debug('++++++++++attachmentList+++'+cdl);
        }Catch(Exception e){  
            system.debug('The error at ' + e.getLineNumber()+ 'cause is'+ e.getMessage()); 
        }

        return result;
    }  
}
```

I am trying insert a document by sending an email in salesforce. as context user mandatory i have given one user. Document is visible to only context user. But i have to visible to all users under one profile.

Can anyone help me how to visible document to all users under one profile?

Comment: do all users have access to the library `ws` ? when you use Inferred `I` Sharetype, the permissions are defined by the library; when you use `AllUsers`, it only applies to CDs linked to objects, not libraries.

Comment: How to check whether all user have access to the library ws or not or give access to library ws?

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
cdl.ContentDocumentId = c.ContentDocumentId;
cdl.ShareType = 'I';
cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
cdl.LinkedEntityId = ws.Id; //Magic happens here
insert cdl;
```

- ShareType = I (implicit) means that the visibility is controlled by the library `ws`
- Visibility = AllUsers only applies when the `LinkedEntityId` is a standard or custom object

You can read about this in the [Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)

> Inferred permission. The user’s permission is determined by the related record. For shares with a library, this is defined by the permissions the user has in that library. Inferred permission on shares with libraries and file owners is available in API versions 21.0 and later. Inferred permission on shares with standard objects is available in API versions 36.0 and later.
>
> AllUsers & InternalUsers values apply to files posted on standard and custom object records, but not to users, groups, or content libraries.

So, to see who has access to the library (Workspace) this [help doc on Library Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_workspace_create.htm&type=5) is the place to start. Every Library has members (which you configure using users/public groups). Thus, to grant access to all profiles, you would use a public group that included all (internal) users. This [help link shows how](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_libraries_add_members.htm&type=5). See also this [Success post on how to do this conveniently with hierarchies](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000eP7iQAE)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to resolve the permission issue for the ContentDocument, giving the permission to "Query All Files" helped me fix the issue.

> Set up > Permission Set > your permission > App permissions > (edit)
> Query All Files

**Refer:** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm